# Correlation coefficient between early procedure and hospitalization.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, correlation, data-analysis, sufficient-statistics

I'm preparing a poster to present in a scientific meeting.
I've done a retrospective research in our hospital database regarding patients undergoing a particular procedure (which is used for people suffering from an acute disease) and check for their hospitalization lenght.

The outcome of this procedure determines the path the patient will follow (surgery or clinical monitoring).

I'm trying to demonstrate that undergoing that procedure earlier leads to a shorter hospitalization lenght. (Our claimings are in **bold**)

I found the correlation coefficient between these 2 variables: "days between entry-procedure", "total lenght of hospitalization".

I get: 
Sample size
37

Correlation coefficient r
0,4739

Significance level
P=0,0030

95% Confidence interval for r
0,1771 to 0,6917

Here's a link to the database: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CAMvweHw2tVb7TBjKvcojXppP478thT4OjxyuQuomfU/edit?usp=sharing

This justify my claiming that **doing the procedure early leads to shorter hospitalization lenght**? Filtering for those who don't qualify for surgery I get even a higher correlation coefficient.

---

I also included previous surgery in the life of these patients. I found that **patients who had a particular type of surgery ("0" in the table) have higher risk to enter the hospital** for that disease, but have also the **highest chance to resolve the issue without surgery**. I don't know how to verify this claiming for statistical significance.

Comment: There maybe formatting problems in the table, I followed this tutorial to insert it https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/ ...

Comment: If someone more familiar with SE could edit the formatting of the table would be highly appreciated! And of coure I thanks anyone who takes time to answer my question. Have a good day.

Comment: Off-topic: IMHO blind statistical analysis cannot replace study of cause and effect. Without being a physician I can think of a couple of causes for your claim, which is itself obviously true and useless for decision making.

Comment: You might try a regression on length of hosp stay on other variables for which you have data for most subjects. Also I'd like to see scatterplots of pairs of variables to see whether relationships are roughly linear. // For future reference, it is difficult to cut/paste data from a table. Easier if each variable is listed in a row with commas separating values, NA or some other symbol for missing data. Do you think there may be useful info in variables other than the first two columns? .

Comment: It is easy to criticize retrospective studies from the sidelines, but sometimes they lead to useful insights. No one analysis of such a study makes an iron-clad argument. But if your poster causes others to look at similar data in various settings, you may have started something important..

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your words of encouragement. I really appreciate them. We've spent a lot of time creating the database and hope that we could find some interesting correlation that corroborate our hypotesis. I've copied the database on Google sheets hoping it will be easier to use. I'd like to know if our statements are supported by statistics before discussing them with colleagues. Othe columns are important for our second claiming: who had an history of surgery ("0") risks more to get sick of this condition and may benefit of an early usage of this procedure. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You could rule reverse causality with the use of instrumental variables.